# Importing shapefiles/kml

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting, location

I need to add support for importing either kml file or shapefiles, preferably using feeds.  The idea is that each record relates to a single node, and the file uploaded could contain hundreds of new nodes.  I've tried [Spatial Tools](https://drupal.org/project/spatial), but the feeds import only works in Drupal 6.  I've also tried [GDAL](https://drupal.org/project/gdal), but it requires the php gdal extension, which has to be compiled.  I'm using windows (not by choice!) and don't have easy access to the compiler and tools necessary, so this is not really an option.  Does anyone know of a way to get either of these to work, or if there is a better way to support importing spatial data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this might help: https://drupal.org/node/1980360 - Importing KML file data into GeoField field instance

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.